# iOS: Tell if user failed to input unlock code

Tags: ios, passwords

I have a little idea for an App, but in order to start I need to figure out a way in which the Application (running in the background) can tell when the user introduces a wrong unlock password.

I've dived the iOS documentation but I can't find how those system calls are handled, and that it is even possible. It would be great if someone can point me out where to start looking.

Well that's it. Cheers from Mexico

Comment: How about a bit more information. How are they entering the code? What exactly do you want it to do? What do you mean by unlock code? Unlock what? I'll be glad to help you.

Comment: The 4-digit the user enter after hitting the home or lock button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're talking about the 4-digit (or complex alphanumeric) passcode the user may enter after hitting the home or lock button after the device has been asleep. iOS does not generate a notification that you can listen for in this situation, so you have no way of knowing what has happened.

To clarify, **this is currently impossible**.

Comment: Precisely... I would need to know when the user inputs a wrong passcode to unlock the iPhone/iPodTouch

Comment: See my post again, I've edited it. What you need to know is impossible to find out.